# ¿Cómo retornar una lista de valores al post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy usando un listbox en mi vista para usar un multiselect. Sucede que al seleccionarlos y darle crear, sólo me toma el primer valor del producto seleccionado, pero yo deseo que me capture todos los valores seleccionados.

En mi controlador hago lo siguiente :

```
Var producto=db.productos.select(x=> new { idprod=x.id_prod, nombre=nombre_prod}).tolist();
ViewBag.producto=new multiselect(producto,"idprod","nombre");
```

En mi vista:

```
@html.listbox(model=>model.idprod, viewbag.producto as multiselectlist)
```

Comment: Donde esta el codigo que recibe la lista con los items marcados?

Comment: Pues eso es lo q no sé hacer, él directamente se va a mi controlador  y solo me pasa un valor

Comment: Creo que debes usar javascript!!! llenando los datos marcados en un array y enviarlos al controlador